# how can i remove an existing file using vc++?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

Iam creating a file called newEntry.txt using vc++ 6.0

```
memset(szLogPath,'\0',sizeof(szLogPath));
strcpy(szLogPath, g_szInstallDir);
strcat(szLogPath, "newentry.txt");
```

and i'm writing some content into that

file.I need to create a new file when ever i run the code instead of writing in the old

file.I can able to create the file but if i try to remove the file using

```
remove("szLogPath");
```

its not removing and the content is appending at the end.How can i remove that file?

Any one can tel me what has to be done to delete that file?

Comment: Post the code you are using to open the file

Comment: You have posted the way you set the `szLogPath`, not the way you are opening the file, anyway you should probably open your file using this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`szLogPath` should be used as a variable, not a string.

```
int remove ( const char * filename );
```

So it should be

```
remove(szLogPath);
```

NOT `remove("szLogPath");`

Comment: ya i fixed that by removing the " ".Now i can delete the file .thanx for the reply